# What would be the contrapositive of a statement about infima?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I need some help for an assignment. I read a theorem that said

> If $S$ is a non-empty and bounded subset of $\Bbb R$, then $\inf S$ is a unique value.

The positive statement would be

> If $\inf S$ is not a unique value then $S$ is empty or unbounded.

Am I correct?

Comment: Will you stop shouting?

Comment: The title of the question should be descriptive, like a short version of the question you are asking. And on the internet, people tend to get annoyed by typing in all caps.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ! I've taken the liberty to edit your question to make it easier to read and answer; as you can see in the two comments above, poor formatting such as caps lock and vague title is not very-well received here. You may also want to look at the introductory tour (https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and the "How do I ask a good question" page in the help center (https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

In general, for a conditional statement $P \Rightarrow Q$, the contrapositive is $\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P$.

Furthermore, a conditional statement is logically equivalent to its contrapositive. You can convince yourself of this by filling out a truth table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the contrapositive, if $S$ is understood as a subset of $\Bbb R$.